# Rigidbody2D AddTorque slow after upgrading to Unity 5

Tags: unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

So my game was working fine with Unity 4.6, but when I imported it into Unity 5, all the Rigidbody2Ds are moving at about a fifth of the rotational velocity they were before when using rigidbody2D.AddTorque().

I can't find any official info about it changing. Any clues?

Thank you!

Comment: I can't find any current information, but [apparently this has been observed before](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/823088/rigidbody2daddtorque-change-has-broken-old-games.html) in an upgrade between versions of 4.5.x.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I found out what was wrong:

There was an animation on the object that had "Apply Root Motion" checked, which caused it to slow down and jitter. Nothing to do with .AddTorque.